# Dash Plotly - Disable Weekends on DatePickerSingle

Tags: python, plotly-dash

```
import dash_core_components as dcc

dcc.DatePickerSingle(
    date=date(2017,6,21),
    display_format='MMM Do, YY'
)
```

How can I disable selecting weekends from date picker?

Answer (score 0):

As of today (June 2021) you can't.

There is an opened [issue](https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/issues/126) regarding this on `dash-core-components`' github.